# What happens to a question that's closed as a dupe to an unanswered question?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

I recently asked a question that was closed as a dupe of another one. The other one has no answer.

I understand that you don't want the dupes and that people should answer the 1st question that was posted. However, is there some way that I could be notified as to when answers to my linked question come in?

Comment: I didn't know that it was possible to close a question as a duplicate of an unanswered question.

Answer (score 3):

You can favorite it (click the star next to the question) and [keep track of activity on your favorite questions](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=favorites&sort=activity).

Answer (score 0):

You can now follow a question (be notified of edits, comments, and answers) by clicking "Follow" beneath it.